# Calculating a programs minimal processing power

Tags: python

I am currently completing a course on Computing Science at school and I was messing around with create new files through the use of python. From this I made   a simple program (just cause it was funny) to make x-amount of files so I could trick my friends into running it on their PC. During this I came across the fact that despite me requesting 10 files, it tended to only create between 4-6 files. Using a minute time delay of about a nano second, this rose to a consistent 9-10 files every time.

I am wondering if there is any method in which I may be able to calculate the minimal processing power a program may use in order for it to reach x% of success? I am just super curious as to how just one nanosecond per loop, drastically changed the output of my program and how this may be perfected to improve the speed of the program (for example, could the nano second become a pico second and still function? How many this effect the chance of a successful file creation). Thank you

Code used in example:

```
import random

#Functions
def createFile(textToWrite):
    entireFile = open(("SpamDocumentName" + str(counter) + ".txt"), "w+")
    entireFile.write(textToWrite)
    entireFile.close()

#Variables to be assigned
run_amount = 10
#Running loop of function
for counter in range(run_amount):
    message = ("Message in text document put here")
    createFile(message)
```

Comment: Post your code here so we can take a look and understand your though. And this way check if was indeed a problem from your code itself.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Are you asking how fast can a computer create new (empty?) files? CPUs clocks are in the order of the nano seconds so anything below that is impossible to achieve and even a couple of nanoseconds are only enough to perform a couple simple arithmetic operations, creating a file requires a system call, which requires a context switch, which requires flushing the L1 caches of the CPU, so it will take at least hundreds/thousands of nanoseconds to run, maybe more.

Comment: @LuanNaufal Similar code added - cant get access to code previously made until I am back in school on Monday :/

Comment: @Bakuriu I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the minimal power a processor would need to run a program to different percentages of success. This would allow me to figure out efficiency of code and calculate the expected output (in the example from post, I was never getting all 10 files created, instead it was 4-6 and this would be a way to calculate the delays etc. necessary to get a 10 file creation everytime)

Comment: The stated behavior, where your loop doesn't fully run, is... atypical. Which is to say, if not all the files were created, there had to be a *reason* for that to happen. There'll be an exception thrown, f/e, which should be included with the question. If, in fact, they *really were* not all created, and what you have isn't just, say, a UI glitch in whatever file browser you were using to *look* at what was or wasn't created.

Comment: But, larger point, there are a lot of assumptions embedded in this question that don't actually ring true; you **never** should need to insert `sleep()`s into a program -- whatever their duration -- to get correct filesystem behavior.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "minimal power". Do you mean amperes? Voltage? Something else? What do you mean by "percentage of success"? Success of what?

Comment: Your code is ok, @CharlieG, and you only missed one aspect that I pointed out in my answer, and now it's working:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53687902/10642035

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Im a newbie at programming, just for some reason or whatever when I did use sleep()  then set it to a nanosecond the files were created 9-10 out of 10 tries, which in comparison to 4-6 was a big difference - my previous assumption was that it just gave the computer time to breath before the next task but I really dont know

Comment: `open(..., O_CREAT)` (the underlying request to the operating system to create a file) is a *blocking* call -- it doesn't finish and return control to your program until after it's done, so no extra "time to breathe" is needed. If you were creating *thousands* of files, garbage collection timing could matter, but  you'd get an explicit exception if the file descriptor table were overrun, and that's not the case here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah okay thank you for clearing that up

Comment: @Bakuriu I meant power as in the CPU and Memory usage the program would consume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a few things on your code:

1. You didn't add the `counter` variable to your function, and since you're writing with `w+`, it's writing on the same file, and this is why you're missing files here.

2. A good practice is to open files with `with open() as name`, and python ensure the closing, and you don't have the risk of loosing info because your file was not closed.

The fixed code would be:

```
import random

#Functions
def createFile(textToWrite, counter):
    with open(("SpamDocumentName" + str(counter) + ".txt"), "w+") as entireFile:
        entireFile.write(textToWrite)


#Variables to be assigned
run_amount = 10
#Running loop of function
for counter in range(run_amount):
    message = ("Message in text document put here")
    createFile(message, counter)
```

Comment: How and where does this actually answer the question the OP asked?

Comment: ...okay, the addition of some explanation helps a little, but I'm not sure these improvements are on-point. Re: (1), if `counter` isn't scope, the code just won't run -- very different from silently reusing an old value and thus overwriting a file. Re: (2), on any graceful exit (not a SIGKILL, not a SIGSEGV, etc), buffers will be flushed regardless, so while `with` is good practice, it doesn't actually fix any pertinent bugs (the OP would have an exception if there actually were any error addressed thusly).

Comment: The point was not the question he asked, @CharlesDuffy, but the question was a since he believed the files were not written for computing reason and not for code miswritten. 
With this code, he solved the goal he was trying to achieve with the code.

Comment: Thank you - may I ask why entireFile.close() was removed? Is this not necessary? Sorry its just in my course notes

Comment: You can still maintain the `createFile` function the same way you did, @CharlieG, it's only a good practice of changing the `entireFile = open..` for `with open... as entireFile`. 
And when you use `with` to open a file, there's no need for the `close()`

Comment: Just don't forget to add `counter` as an argument for your function, as it was not included.

Comment: In case it solved your problem, don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one, @CharlieG. And if you have any trouble with my solution, just add here and I check for you.